# Zclip not copy text

Tags: javascript, jquery, clipboard, zclip

Zclip plugin not copy text.

```
    <head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
</head>
<button id = "copy-description">132</button>
<p id = "description">123456789132456789</p>
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#copy-description').click(function(){
        $('#copy-description').zclip({
            path:'ZeroClipboard.swf',
            copy:function(){return $('p#description').val();}

        });
    });
});
</script>
```

When i click on button, my clipboard not change. I try with jQuery v1.11.1, and v 1.6
Thanks For help.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: no, after click my clipboard clean

Comment: Remove the spaces between the `type = ` and `src = ` and `id = `.  See answer below as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/LNd6p/

This should work.  I got rid of the space for your `id` tags in the HTML.

```
<button id="copy-description">132</button>
<p id="description">123456789132456789</p>
```

Then changed `.val()` to `.text()` since we're getting the text from a div not a form element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#copy-description').click(function(){
        $('#copy-description').zclip({
            path:'http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/zclip/1.1.2/ZeroClipboard.swf', //you can change this back to your local version, I had to to this for testing.
            copy:function(){
                return $('#description').text(); //changed .val() to .text()
            } 
        });
    });
});
```